# Executing TI BASIC from a String

Tags: ti-basic

Is it possible to Execute TI BASIC from a string? Such that:
`execute(":Disp Str1")`
would Print out Str1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not like this- expr and eval only work on expressions.

Comment: This is what I was hoping I didn't have to do, but I've heard that you can execute Assembly from the TI BASIC Program, Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is! Asm(prgmMYASMPGM

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It could be done with a small `Asm(` program that takes a string (from `Ans`), turns it into a BASIC program, and executes it. For example:

```
.nolist
#include "ti83plus.inc"
.list
    .org userMem-2
    .db $BB,$6D
    ld hl,SavesScreen
    ld (hl),tTheta
    inc hl
    ld (hl),0
    inc hl
    push hl
    bcall(_AnsName)
    rst rFindSym
    ex de,hl
    ld c,(hl)
    inc hl
    ld b,(hl)
    dec hl
    inc bc
    inc bc
    pop de
    ldir
    ld hl,SavesScreen
    ld a,6
    bcall(_ExecuteNewPrgm)
    ; no ret because _ExecuteNewPrgm does not return
```

**This is not ideal,**

- No safety in case `Ans` did not contain a string (could be added).
- A program named θ should not exist, because it will be overwritten. If `prgmθ` already exists and is archived, then it does not work at all. (could be improved)
- `prgmθ` is not deleted afterwards. (not sure how to do this)
- When `prgmθ` is done, it quits to the Homescreen, it does not return to the calling program. (not sure how to do this)

Aside from that, it does work, for example:

```
:"TESTING->Str1
:":Disp Str1
:Asm(prgmRUNSTR
```

Looks like this afterwards:

[image: screen]

You can create the assembly program by typing this into a normal program:

```
AsmPrgmBB6D21
EC86365B2336
0023E5EF524B
D7EB4E23462B
0303D1EDB021
EC863E06EF3C
4C
```

It can be made smaller with [`AsmComp(`](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/asmcomp).